# binormal vectors and generalized helix

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

There's a problem I'm stucked on it. I wonder if anybody is able to help me because I tried almost every idea that I could thougth of. Here it is:

If $ u $ is a fixed direction and for any point $ s $ of a space curve

$ \left< B(s) , u \right> = \mathrm{constant} $

holds then prove that there's a constant vector $ v $ such that for every point $ s $ we have
$ \left< T,v \right> = \mathrm{constant} $

I wish somebody could help me.

[ $ B $ is the binormal vector of curve. ]
[ the curve is prameterized with arc length ]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's some guide to [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\langle B(s), u\rangle = c$ then $\langle B'(s), u\rangle + \langle B(s), u'\rangle = 0$. But $u$ is constant, so $\langle B(s), u'\rangle = 0$ and therefore $\langle B(s), u\rangle ' = \langle B'(s), u\rangle = 0$.

Using the Frenet Serret formulas, $\langle B'(s), u\rangle = \tau(s) \langle N(s), u\rangle = 0$ , so either the torsion is zero or $\langle N(s), u\rangle$ is zero.

Let $\alpha(s)$ be the curve such that its binormal vector makes a constant angle with $u$.

- *Case 1:* If $\tau(s)$ is thero then the curve lies in its osculating plane and the binormal vector ( which is the normal vector of that plane ) is constant, so $T$ makes a constant angle with the constant direction $B$.
- *Case 2:* if $\langle N(s), u\rangle=0$ then $\langle N(s), u\rangle ' = 0$, so $\langle N'(s), u\rangle = 0$. On the other hand, $\langle T(s), u\rangle ' = \langle T'(s), u\rangle $ and using the Frenet Serret formulas again $\langle T'(s), u\rangle  = k(s)\langle N(s), u\rangle = k(s) \cdot 0 = 0$, so $\langle T(s), u\rangle $ is constant.